# Keeping tag name when transforming XML into List using R

Tags: xml, r

I have an XML file that looks like this:

```
<Events>
        <AA Time="45"  X="497" Y="220" />
        <AA Time="46"  X="513" Y="206" />
        <AB Time="187" X="492" Y="237" />
        <BB Time="187" X="40"  Y="152" />
        <BA Time="187" X="40" />
        <AC Time="187" X="40" />
</Events>
```

I transformed the XML data into a list using R:

```
require(XML)
require(plyr)
data <- xmlParse("myfile.xml")
xml_data <- xmlToList(data)
eventslist <- as.list(xml_data[["Events"]])
mylist <- rbind.fill(lapply(eventslist,function(y) {as.data.frame(t(y),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)}))
```

Everything works fine, but I can't find a way to include the tag names (AA, AB, BC etc.) as rows in an "Event Type" column. What should I do?

Comment: Just as simple as that? It did work. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add back the names from the list as a column to the data.frame, just do

```
mylist$EventType <- names(eventslist)
```